# Why is Gazebo not loading a model?

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to work with Gazebo using xacro files. It seems that it works with Rviz, but there is no model in Gazebo. Please take a look at the files here: https://github.com/matrhint/model-problems  I am running Kinetic. I am using roslaunch lawnmow_description lawnmow_rviz.launch and roslaunch lawnmow_gazebo lawnmow_world.launch to test it out.

Thank you for any assistance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260158/why-is-gazebo-not-loading-a-model?/) by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-25**:
In your URDF and xacro files, you shouldn't have absolute paths to resources like meshes. Use the package:// syntax instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I changed all the mesh paths in `lawnmow.xacro` to use the `package://` syntax, Gazebo displayed the model when I launched `lawnmow_world.launch`.
[image: image description]

For example, the first one I changed to:

```
package://lawnmow_description/meshes/frame.stl
```

I also had to add `<intertial>` tags to the `lfcaster` and `rfcaster` links, because Gazebo will not simulate links that do not have inertia information.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-25**:
Thank you for your fast response! That is exactly what I want. I tried: `<mesh scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" filename="package://lawnmow_description/meshes/frame.stl"/>` and it didn't work for me. I then changed it to `<mesh filename="package://lawnmow_description/meshes/frame.stl"/>` another no-go.

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-25**:
Edit: I was changing the wrong file. Your suggestion was correct. Thank you for your fast response and clear answer!

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-25**:
Any ideas why the front casters aren't showing up in gazebo?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
You don't have `<intertial>` tags in the two caster links. Gazebo will only use links that have intertia information.

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-26**:
You are my hero, but it didn't work. I copied the `<inertial>` information from the left_wheel and placed it after the `</visual>` tab, but still no casters.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
Can you put a copy of your lawnmow.xacro somewhere so I can see? I did exactly that and I get casters.

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-26**:
I updated it on the github. Thanks again.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
Using your exact source in Kinetic, and running `roslaunch lawnmow_gazebo lawnmow_world.launch`, I get casters. Does Gazebo print any errors at all? Have you tried cleaning your workspace?

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-26**:
I tried catkin_make clean and still no casters. I get red writing when gazebo is launched that says gazebo-2 process has died pid 29628 and goes on to say where the log file is.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
Every time? If Gazebo is crashing, you will need to fix that problem first.

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-26**:
Yes every time. I will open a new question for that issue. Thank you so much for all of your help.

**Comment by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) on 2017-04-26**:
killall gzserver fixed the issues. I now have casters in Gazebo!

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
Great! I'll add the extra info to the answer.